# row bind list columns using dplyr

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to find a better way to bind together the results of any number of regressions after adding an identifier for each model.  The code below is my current solution but is too manual for a large number of regressions. This is part of a larger tidy workflow so a solution inside of the `tidyverse` is preferred but whatever works is fine. Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

model_dat=mtcars %>% 
do(lm_1 = tidy(lm(disp~ wt*vs, data = .),conf.int=T),
   lm_2=tidy(lm(cyl ~ wt*vs, data = .),conf.int=T ),
   lm_3=tidy(lm(mpg ~ wt*vs, data = .),conf.int=T ))
df=model_dat %>%
    select(lm_1) %>%
    unnest(c(lm_1)) %>%
    mutate(model="one") %>% 
    select(model,term,estimate,p.value:conf.high) %>%
    bind_rows(
        model_dat %>% 
            select(lm_2) %>% 
            unnest(c(lm_2)) %>% 
            mutate(model="two") %>% 
            select(model,term,estimate,p.value:conf.high)) %>%
    bind_rows(
        model_dat %>% 
            select(lm_3) %>% 
            unnest(c(lm_3)) %>% 
            mutate(model="three") %>% 
            select(model,term,estimate,p.value:conf.high))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be easier with `map2` i.e. loop across the columns and the corresponding `english` word for the sequence of columns, `pluck` the `list` element, create the 'model' column with second argument i.e. `engish` words (`.y`), `select` the columns of interest, and create a single dataset by specifying `_dfr` in `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(english)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
map2_dfr(model_dat, as.character(english(seq_along(model_dat))), 
      ~ .x  %>% 
           pluck(1) %>%
           mutate(model = .y) %>% 
           select(model, term, estimate, p.value:conf.high) )
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 6
#   model term        estimate  p.value conf.low conf.high
#   <chr> <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 one   (Intercept) -70.0    1.55e- 1 -168.       28.2  
# 2 one   wt          102.     8.20e- 9   76.4     128.   
# 3 one   vs           31.2    6.54e- 1 -110.      172.   
# 4 one   wt:vs       -36.7    1.10e- 1  -82.2       8.82 
# 5 two   (Intercept)   4.31   1.28e- 5    2.64      5.99 
# 6 two   wt            0.849  4.90e- 4    0.408     1.29 
# 7 two   vs           -2.19   7.28e- 2   -4.59      0.216
# 8 two   wt:vs         0.0869 8.20e- 1   -0.689     0.862
# 9 three (Intercept)  29.5    6.55e-12   24.2      34.9  
#10 three wt           -3.50   2.33e- 5   -4.92     -2.08 
#11 three vs           11.8    4.10e- 3    4.06     19.5  
#12 three wt:vs        -2.91   2.36e- 2   -5.40     -0.419
```

---

Or use `summarise` with `across`, `unclass` and then bind with `bind_rows`

```
model_dat %>% 
       summarise(across(everything(), ~ {
         # // get the column name
         nm1 <- cur_column()
         # // extract the list element (.[[1]])
         list(.[[1]] %>% 
            # // create new column by extracting the numeric part
            mutate(model = english(readr::parse_number(nm1))) %>%
            # // select the subset of columns, wrap in a list
            select(model, term, estimate, p.value:conf.high))
         }
         )) %>%
        # // unclass to list
        unclass %>%
        # // bind the list elements
        bind_rows
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 6
#   model     term        estimate  p.value conf.low conf.high
#   <english> <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 one       (Intercept) -70.0    1.55e- 1 -168.       28.2  
# 2 one       wt          102.     8.20e- 9   76.4     128.   
# 3 one       vs           31.2    6.54e- 1 -110.      172.   
# 4 one       wt:vs       -36.7    1.10e- 1  -82.2       8.82 
# 5 two       (Intercept)   4.31   1.28e- 5    2.64      5.99 
# 6 two       wt            0.849  4.90e- 4    0.408     1.29 
# 7 two       vs           -2.19   7.28e- 2   -4.59      0.216
# 8 two       wt:vs         0.0869 8.20e- 1   -0.689     0.862
# 9 three     (Intercept)  29.5    6.55e-12   24.2      34.9  
#10 three     wt           -3.50   2.33e- 5   -4.92     -2.08 
#11 three     vs           11.8    4.10e- 3    4.06     19.5  
#12 three     wt:vs        -2.91   2.36e- 2   -5.40     -0.419
```

Comment: Wow that is clever!  I just realized I posed my question incorrectly I actually need the dependent variable to change in each model. I think the solution would still work but would you mind taking a look at the edit?

Comment: @tetime it wouldn't change the code.  I updated with your new data though